# Как мапить index.html

Tags: javascript, java, html

Как java понимает, что путь в браузере http://localhost:8080/index это index.html ? 
У меня в данный момент открывает только если прописать явно http://localhost:8080/index.html

Comment: Всё правильно. Так и должно быть. Сам по себе сервер не будет показывать на запрос index index.html. Его надо как-то настроить на выполнение такой подмены. Это зависит от того какой сервер, что за index.html - статический файл или формируется servlet-ом?

Comment: Сервер Tomcat на Spring Boot e. Html статические

Comment: Если статический, то искать на тему rewrite rule наверное. Не знаю есть ли такая функция в tomcat или spring, но упоминания о каких-то решениях встречал. Особо изощрённый способ - установка revers proxy перед tomcat (nginx например) они-то точно умеют всё переписывать. Суть в том, чтобы в запросе index заменялся на index.html и сервер видел index.html (о который он всё знает)

Comment: Вопрос не относится ни к Java, ни к JavaScript, ни даже к HTML, а к конфигурации сервера, отдающего файл.

Comment: Tomcat - это скорей всего контенер servlet-ов на java и для java, Spring вероятно известный фреймворк для java. Вряд ли кто-то не знакомый с этой javа возьмётся конфигурировать этот сервер. Тем более когда в нём url rewrite осуществляется каким-нибудь сторонним фильтром тоже на java. Всюду эта java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть такая штука как [Согласование контета (Content Negotiation)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_negotiation): в зависимости от параметров, которые отправляет клиент, сервер выбирает наиболее подходящий для клиента контент, удовлетворяющий всем требованиям. Например, на сайте могут быть два файла:

- index.html
- index.txt

Если клиент запросит `index` без расширения и укажет в запросе

```
Accept: text/html
```

то сервер выберет `index.html`.

В серверах Apache за подобный выбор отвечает модуль [mod_negotiation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_negotiation.html). Подобную «подмену» контента нужно явно включать на сервере.

---

См. также: [Content Negotiation on Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592983/content-negotiation-on-tomcat)

Для подобного преобразования также могут использоваться [`RewriteRule`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/rewrite.html).

Comment: Про content negotiation инфа скорей для общей эрудиции. Сомнительное отношение к обрисованной проблеме. А всякие rewrite - верное направление. И BalusC чувак авторитетный.

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас стандартное Java Web приложение, то в файле `WEB-INF/web.xml` вы можете явно указать, какое имя файла подставлять по умолчанию. Это делается следующим образом:

```html
<welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>/index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```